# Multi Select in angular 6

Tags: html, angular, ngx-bootstrap, bootstrap-multiselect

[image]

what plugin in angular gives similar multi-select, I have already installed ng-bootstrap. I want to show options grouped with the option of selecting an entire group. **in angular 6**

Comment: See: [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What have you looked at so far? What code have you tried?

Comment: This will help:https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview

Comment: @rohan How did you go about it? What library you have used?